# capture git branch name in makefile variable

Tags: git, awk, makefile

I am writing a Makefile and would like to capture the current branch name in a variable to be passed into a --define. 
Since the script sometimes but not always runs on travis the git repository might be in detached state.

I can extract the branch name on the command line but unfortunately not capture it in a variable. It seems as if the print $$2 does not work within the Makefile environment.

My current line is:

```
BRANCH := $(shell git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/heads | awk "/^$$(git rev-parse HEAD)/ {print $$2}")
```

and I get

```
dfd943a57015dbd2129ca7b7033c4e1749f18974 BRANCH_NAME
```

instead of just

```
 BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: try `awk "/$(git rev-parse HEAD)/{print \$2}"`

Comment: I have to write it like this but your tip with the backslash worked! awk "/$$(git rev-parse HEAD)/{print \$$2}"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you want as the result if `git rev-parse HEAD` produces a hash that does not match *any* branch name?

Comment: @torek In that case an empty string is fine. I just want to display a human readable description for the current source if possible. Otherwise it is just the hash.

Comment: That seems like a LOT of work just to get the current branch name.  Why not just use something like `BRANCH := $(shell git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)` ?

Comment: @MadScientist The reason is that I want a description for a detached head. Since travis checks out the source in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked best for me is:

```
BRANCH := $(shell git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/heads | awk "/^$$(git rev-parse HEAD)/ {print \$$2}")
HASH := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Those variables can then be used e.g. with `$(BRANCH)`

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer has a problem reliably extracting the branch name (the hash is ok). If the current HEAD commit is the current head of multiple branches then the value of BRANCH will be "branch1 branch2", which will produce unexpected results in your Makefile.

Simply use:

```
BRANCH := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
HASH := $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right way to abuse the shell usage in bash , but

```
    .PHONY: git-snapshot  ## @-> for your current commit into a new timestamped branch
    git-snapshot:
      @clear
      @$(eval current_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`)
      @$(eval current_hash=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`)
      @$(eval current_time=`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`)
      @git branch "${current_branch}--${current_time}-${current_hash}"
      git branch -a | grep ${current_branch} | sort -nr
```

usage

```
    make git-snapshot
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_072846-9f32fa5
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_072721-9f32fa5
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_071720-9f32fa5
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_071719-9f32fa5
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_071718-9f32fa5
    3063--data-cleaning--20230311_071716-9f32fa5
  * 3063--data-cleaning
```